# Checking if user has Google+ BEFORE sign-in to app?

Tags: google-api, google-plus

I'm using Google API with "google-signin-callback" in order to monitor the Google status of the user. What I **want** is the following logic:

```
if (/* [1] user is logged-in to Google */) {
  if (/* [2] user has Google+ */) {
    /* call gapi.auth.signIn with scope="https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login" */
  }
  else {
    /* call gapi.auth.signIn with scope="profile" (so not to force upgrade) */
  }
}
```

The good news is that by using page-level parameters I get the "google-signin-callback" called right at the beginning, before the user actually did anything. So I am able to check the `response.status.google_logged_in` in order to check [1] above.

The bad news is that I don't see any immediate way of checking [2] above. I can check it **after** the user has signed in, by checking the profile of 'me' with `gapi.client.plus.people.get` ... but then it's too late.

Any remedy?

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to tell if an unauthenticated user has  Google+ profile. It would be a violation of their privacy to do so.

Comment: At best you can find out if the user has a valid Google (not Google+) session: https://developers.google.com/+/web/api/javascript#gapiauthchecksessionstatesessionparams_callback